# Android: method (same name) persistent between activities?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, methods, overriding

I have an activity with an overrided method (onData) from a library (emdk ir scan).
I also have another activity with the same method doing other things.
It needs to be "duplicated" if you use it on more than one activity, it's in their documentation.

Error: error Activity  has leaked ServiceConnection com.symbol.emdk.EMDKServiceConnection@fd186e9 that was originally bound here

The problem is, when I switch between activities (new intent and finish), it seems to use the old onData onstead of the one in the new activity.

Example: I'm in activity 1, and the user use the onData method from this activity (obviously) and it's all ok. Then he switch to the activity 2, and here when it work it happen to use the onData from the activity 1 instead of the one in the activity 2 :-|

Don't know if I have explained it, but it's complex :-)

```
@Override
public void onData(ScanDataCollection scanDataCollection) {
    bla bla bla
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    deInitScanner();
    if (barcodeManager != null) {
        barcodeManager.removeConnectionListener(this);
        barcodeManager = null;
        deviceList = null;
    }
    if (emdkManager != null) {
        emdkManager.release(EMDKManager.FEATURE_TYPE.BARCODE);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (emdkManager != null) {
        barcodeManager = (BarcodeManager) emdkManager.getInstance(EMDKManager.FEATURE_TYPE.BARCODE);
        if (barcodeManager != null) {
            barcodeManager.addConnectionListener(this);
        }
        enumerateScannerDevices();
        spinnerScannerDevices.setSelection(scannerIndex);
        try {
            initScanner();
        } catch (ScannerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        scanner.triggerType = Scanner.TriggerType.HARD;
    }
}
```

Comment: when is this onData called?

Comment: directly after the scan with IR

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you initialize this SDK with something like `scanner.addDataListener(this)` , `this` being the activity 1. It holds a reference of this activity 1 within itself so every time you request it, it calls the `onData` for the activity 1.

You can either reinitialize it with the new activity, or with an outside listener which you can listen to from everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You should subscribe on events in onResume and unsubscribe in onPause. If I understand which library you use (EMDK for Android) this code will be:

```java
@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    BarcodeScanner.getInstance(this);
    BarcodeScanner.registerUIobject(this);
}
```

and

```
@Override
 public void onPause() {
     super.onPause();
     BarcodeScanner.unregisterUIobject();
 }
```

So only one activity will listen this events

Comment: in which activity callback you setup listener in second activity?

Comment: did you debugged callback call order? (what subscribe/unsubscribe parts of your activities fork fine and not overlap)

Comment: when I switch from the first activity to the second (no matter what is the order), the onData is not called anymore (with error Activity  has leaked ServiceConnection com.symbol.emdk.EMDKServiceConnection@fd186e9 that was originally bound here): I need to go to an activity without ALL the code related to this problem, and then return to the activity I want.

Comment: not sure why, but solved cutting off the content of the Parenthesis here in onPause: emdkManager.release(EMDKManager.FEATURE_TYPE.BARCODE);

Error log persist, but it's working